# Reading from binary file LANG C

Tags: c, windows, printing, binary, scanning

I am having trouble reading from a bin file.
I am recording some text in binary (correctly i think), but my code isn't able to read the text I wrote and print it in the console. When i open the file the information is there (this document is use to storage the information from the client and the login access) and i can login, but when i try to read and print in console it doesn't show me.
I am using a struct to get the values from the document, and then i open the document "fopen()"  but when i try to read with the "fread()" in a "while" I don't get in, the print don't give me the right information

I try to reduce as much i could of the code.

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <string.h>
#include <locale.h>
#include <dir.h>
#include <unistd.h>
#include <time.h>
#include <conio.h>
#define SIZE 1000

typedef struct
{
char id[10];
char nome[100];
char passe[100];
}Pacient;
Pacient p1;

FILE* filepaciente;

//variables
char tmpnome[100], tmppassword[100];

//variable for path
char nomedoc[15];
char pasta[250];
char sessionName[15];
char tmp_name[15];
char fullpath[200];
char tmp_nome[15];

void vedocumento(int* i, char* line, char pacienteData[])
{
    // DEFINE A VARIÁVEL USERDATA COMO UMA STRING VAZIA
    strcpy(pacienteData, "");
    // IF FINDS "|", GO TO THE NEXT CHARACTER
    if (line[*i] == '|')
    {
        (*i)++;
    }
    //WHEN THE CHARACTER IS DIFERENT THEN |, ADD THAT CHARACTER TO THE ARRAY USERDATA
    while (line[*i] != '|') // *i = 0
    {
        strncat(pacienteData, &line[*i], 1); // userData = "" ; userData = userData + carater
        (*i)++;
    }
}
findpath()
{
    //PROCURA O CAMINHO ONDE SE ENCONTRA O PROJETO

    if (getcwd(pasta, sizeof(pasta)) == NULL)
    {
        printf("ERROR!\n");
    }
    else
    {
        strcat(pasta, "\\file\\");
        //CRIA O FICHEIRO COM O NUMERO DE INTERNO
        strcpy(nomedoc, strcat(tmp_nome, ".bin"));
        //JUNTA O CAMINHO COMPLETO AO NOME DO FICHEIRO
        strcat(pasta, nomedoc);
        strcpy(fullpath, pasta);
    }
}

int main() //where i write in the bin file
{
    //GETTING REGISTRY DATA
    fflush(stdin); //para ir so buscar os dados
    printf("\nName pacient: ");
    scanf("%[^\n]", p1.nome);
    printf("\nPassword do pacient %s: ", p1.nome);
    scanf("%s", p1.passe);
    printf("\nID pacient %s: ", p1.nome);
    scanf(" %s", p1.id);
    strcpy(tmp_nome, p1.nome);
    strcpy(tmp_nome, strlwr(tmp_nome));

    findpath();
     if (access(fullpath, F_OK) == 0)
    {
        //IF EXISTS
        printf("Este nome de utilizador já foi registado! Por favor, tente novamente!\n");
    }
    else
    {
        // IF DOESN'T EXIST
        filepaciente = fopen(fullpath, "wb");
        if (filepaciente == NULL)
        {
            printf("\nerror\n");
        }
        
        //size_t elements_written = fwrite(&p1, sizeof(Paciente), 1, filepaciente);
        
        //PRINTING ON FILE
        
        fprintf(filepaciente, "%s|%s|%s\n", p1.nome, p1.passe, p1.id);
        fclose(filepaciente);
    }

  //WHERE I WANT TO PRINT ON THE CONSOLE
{
    printf("Name do pacient: ");
    scanf(" %[^\n]", tmpnome);

    strcpy(tmp_nome, tmpnome);
    strcpy(tmp_nome, strlwr(tmp_nome));//this is to get the name of the document
    
    findpath(); //Find the path to the document
    if (access(fullpath, F_OK) == 0)
    {
        filepaciente = fopen(fullpath, "rb"); //Open the document
        Pacient pacient[100];
        char line[SIZE];
        int nline = 0;
        fgets(line, SIZE, filepaciente);
        int i = 0;
        vedocumento(&i, line, pacient[nline].nome);
        vedocumento(&i, line, pacient[nline].passe);
        nline++;
        //LOOP TO CHECK
        for (i = 0; i < 1; i++)
        {   
            if (strcmp(tmpnome, pacient[i].nome) == 0)
            {   //WRITE INFO
                char buf[SIZE];
                if (filepaciente == NULL)
                { 
                    printf("\nERRO OPENING\n");
                }else printf("\nOPEN THE FILE\n");
                //IF I PUT "==1" DON'T GET IN THE WHILE
                while( fread(&p1, sizeof(p1), 1, filepaciente) == 1) 
                {
                    printf("%c", p1); //NOT SURE IF THIS IS CORRECT
                }
            }
        }
    }
}
}
```

Comment: Code shown is incomplete. Please provide a [complete minimal verifiable example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example). Include the code that calls these functions and also the exact input, expected result and actual result.

Comment: I think that you have now all the information you need. If you need more tell me, i will try to edit or answer.

Comment: https://mega.nz/file/5NUXmaqR#duHpEu9WycsLVIEnyyZ9OFM8YYN9cKob_HlK5QdXpoA Here you have my program in a ZIP, after you execute: 1º - input "2"; 2º - input "k" for username and "k" for password; 3º - input "2"; 4º - input "r"; we arrive to the problem here, i should get on the console what is written in the file "r" but nothing appears. Sorry about the code not being (well) translated

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow! Please read the information linked to by @kaylum carefully and try to change your question accordingly. You should provide the code in the question, not in a zip file, and equally important, you should shorten your program as to illustrate the problem with as few lines of code left as possible. As kaylum wrote you also need to provide the code that calls the code in question, the input and expected result.

Comment: Ok,i try to compile the code but is too big to post as coment so i will edit the code of the post. Unfortunately i couldn't make it creating a new directory to storage the file, if you can, create a folder with the name "file" in the directory that the program is runing. Here is a link with the folder and everything created already, ready to test.  THE LINK: https://mega.nz/file/pQMXGCBL#H0FYITEANQ2snldCMlTKpC-WJSv7Rxvn3GMnL5UcZIg